# Generating a 3D uniform mesh in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create four 11 by 11 by 11(since we start from 0) uniform arrays called X (for X domain), Y, Z and W. The space domains (X,Y,Z) should be from 0 to 100 (assuming cm), so the uniform mesh is 10cm of length (X), depth (Y) and height (Z). I also want to generate a function like a Gaussian exp (-x^2-y^2-z^2)) distributed in X,Y,Z domains and stored in W. I am stuck on how do I generate the 4 arrays I need as well as how to generate the uniform mesh. I have tried to use meshgrid but I cant get the correct surface plots. Any help is appreciated

Comment: what do you mean by: "exp (-x2-y 2-z2))" ?

Comment: that was supposed to be an expression for gaussian distribution

Comment: `W` is a function of 3 variables. How will you get a *surface plot* (i.e. a function of 2 variables) from that?

Comment: you are right about that . I can not create  a surface plot using more than 2 variables. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to generate your independent variables `X`, `Y`, and `Z` like so:

```
[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(0:10:100);
```

Now, you can easily compute a dependent variable `W` using the above matrices and [element-wise array operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html). For your example formula:

```
W = exp(X.^2+Y.^2+Z.^2);
```

Note that the [`.^` operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html) is used to raise each element of the matrix to a power.